# For loop not working with numerically labelled directories

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've never had this problem: I have a few numerically numbered folders so I can loop through the files or even use parallelisation without worrying about all the file names being totally different.

In this case, I separated all of my files into folders labelled `sample_1` to `sample_18` and used a *super simple* for loop:

```
for i in {1..18};
do
  cd sample_${i}
  mv *.fa sample_${i}.fa
  mv *.gff sample_${i}.gff
  mv *.bam sample_${i}.bam
  mv *.sam sample_${i}.sam
  cd ..
done
```

It works fine for 1-9 and then doesn't work in the double digits. It will literally give the error that the directory sample_10 doesn't exist. I ventured it had something to do with bash thinking it was 1 and then 0 instead of 10 when I named the directories but I honestly don't know how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit:

Showing what an ll command produces. All the directories are there.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 anm5579 mls164_collab  644 Sep 18 11:18 contentsInfo
-rw-rw---- 1 anm5579 mls164_collab   44 Sep 27 16:07 fixdata.sh
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_1
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 21 17:08 sample_10
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 18 10:59 sample_11
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 20 11:11 sample_12
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 21 17:12 sample_13
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 18 11:12 sample_14
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 18 11:11 sample_15
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 21 10:40 sample_16
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 20 11:08 sample_17
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 18 11:11 sample_18
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_2
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_3
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_4
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_5
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_6
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_7
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_8
drwxrws--- 2 anm5579 mls164_collab 4096 Sep 27 15:59 sample_9
```

Error produced is just no directory found for samples 10-18.

Showing what hexdump produces with: `echo sample_* | hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f 31  20 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f  |sample_1 sample_|
00000010  31 30 20 73 61 6d 70 6c  65 5f 31 31 20 73 61 6d  |10 sample_11 sam|
00000020  70 6c 65 5f 31 32 20 73  61 6d 70 6c 65 5f 31 33  |ple_12 sample_13|
00000030  20 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f  31 34 20 73 61 6d 70 6c  | sample_14 sampl|
00000040  65 5f 31 35 20 73 61 6d  70 6c 65 5f 31 36 20 73  |e_15 sample_16 s|
00000050  61 6d 70 6c 65 5f 31 37  20 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f  |ample_17 sample_|
00000060  31 38 20 73 61 6d 70 6c  65 5f 32 20 73 61 6d 70  |18 sample_2 samp|
00000070  6c 65 5f 33 20 73 61 6d  70 6c 65 5f 34 20 73 61  |le_3 sample_4 sa|
00000080  6d 70 6c 65 5f 35 20 73  61 6d 70 6c 65 5f 36 20  |mple_5 sample_6 |
00000090  73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f 37  20 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f  |sample_7 sample_|
000000a0  38 20 73 61 6d 70 6c 65  5f 39 0a                 |8 sample_9.|
000000ab
```

Comment: That sample_10 directory name may contain invisible / non printable characters. `echo * | hd` is your friend.

Comment: In general, you should include the exact error message you get in your question. But I'll assume the error comes from the `cd`. Since you mention naming the directories, it would be useful to see how you did that, exactly. Or a listing of the directories that actually exist, like mosvy commented.

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry. I added the output of an ll to show all the directories are present. The error was just "No such file or directory" for all samples 10-18.

Comment: @Fabby "-bash: hd: command not found" ah. The wonders of working on other people's computers.

Comment: @Fabby Luckily hexdump worked. I doubt I would have permissions for installations but maybe. I added the output. Sorry such a small question has turned into something so big. I have no idea how to read the output of hexdump, though, or glean anything from it.

Comment: try adding a `pwd` line before the `cd sample_${i}`. If I was you, I would always put commands that change the directory in a subshell, eg.; `for ...; do (cd ...; ...); done`.

Comment: @Lexi Please [try again](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83761/room-for-fabby-and-lexi)

Comment: Is it *really* the `cd` command that's failing - or is it `mv` that's failing, because one of your shell globs expands to more than one file and (for example) `target 'sample_10.fa' is not a directory`?

Comment: Try `printf "%q\n" sample_*/` -- I wonder if the bare echo might be stripping off control characgters.

Comment: Please, put you snippet in a script file. Use `#!/bin/bash -vx` as the first line. Check the output and verify which command is printing the error message.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message? It would include the name of the utility that failed (`cd` or `mv` most likely).  If it's `mv`, then you have more than one of the types of files that you are trying to rename in one of the directories.

Answer (score 2):

Test it manually, step by step, debugging when you meet problems.

```
i=10
cd sample_${i}
mv *.fa sample_${i}.fa
mv *.gff sample_${i}.gff
mv *.bam sample_${i}.bam
mv *.sam sample_${i}.sam
cd ..
```

If it says `sample_10 doesn't exist`, check it.

Comment: I did check this. It says it doesn't exist. I also echoed ${i} during the loop to make sure it was working correctly and it was. It's been a rough day.

Comment: @Lexi You're focusing on the wrong problem. Your directory actually doesn't exit.

Comment: @Lexi But did you check if it did exist in fact, was a directory and you could enter it?

Comment: Yep. If I just cd sample_10 from the regular command line, it works. There's even files in it. Somehow when it's put into a loop, it doesn't work. Also forgot to highlight that it doesn't work for any of the directories 10-18. When it's in the double digits, it no longer works in the for loop.

Comment: @Lexi You need to debug. Use shellcheck.net first to make sure there's no obvious trap. Then you have the `-x` debugging option in Bash.

Comment: @Lexi When mentioning an error message, it's important to include what utility it is that gives the error. In this case, it's a world of difference between `cd` reporting an error and `mv` reporting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is faulty somewhere and that you have a duplicate file in Sample_9 and that *this* is what makes the command fail, but as this is too cumbersome to type in a comment and you seem to be off-line so I cannot invite you into chat, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
for i in {1..18};
do
  (
    cd "sample_${i}"
    pwd
  )
done
```

and provide the output of the above into your question.  We'll take it from there.

Comment: Leave a comment @Fabby here after you've done that and I'll re-appear from my magic lamp.  **;-)**